# windows phone 7 and Sqlite database

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-7

In android, sqlite database can see from command line use of platform tools. In windows phone 7, how can I see sqlite database from command line?

Comment: I don't have the answer to this question, but I'm puzzled why someone voted it down.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about using SqLite database in windows phone but all the database related stuff in windows phone happen in the [Isolate Storage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402541%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) allocated to your application.

To access the files stored in the Isolated Storage you need to use the [Isolated Storage Explorer Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which is distributed along with the SDK.